# Stata: multiple xlines with label

Tags: stata

I want to create a histogram with two xlines representing female_mean and male_mean, with separate labels for each xlines. However, there is a line that connects the labels of the two xlines and I want to get rid of it. Here is a sample data and code for replication

```
clear all
input  female scale
 1 3
 1 4
 0 2
 1 4
 0 3
 1 4
 0 2
 1 9
 0 5
 0 6
 1 7
end

su scale if female==1
local female_mean=round(r(mean), 0.01)
local female_mean: di %9.2f round(r(mean), 0.01)

su scale if female==0
local male_mean=round(r(mean), 0.01)
local male_mean: di %9.2f round(r(mean), 0.01)

* Create scale Histogram by gender
twoway (histogram scale if female == 1, percent discrete xaxis(1 2) xla(`female_mean' "`female_mean'" `male_mean' "`male_mean'", axis(2) format(%9.3f)) xline(`female_mean' `male_mean')) ///
       (histogram scale if female == 0, percent discrete), legend(order(1 "Female" 2 "Male"))
```

[image: Replicating Nick's code]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the reproducible example. I can't work out what you're referring to. I see no line connecting labels.

But I can't see several details that don't help or can be improved.

1. The `round()` doesn't help here. In fact `round()` with second argument less than 1 often does puzzling things as a side-effect of storage and calculations being in binary. Pushing means through a display format is sufficient for all your purposes.
2. The two groups really must be assigned different colours.
3. It's a matter of taste, but I find a cosmetic gap between bars helpful for such data.
4. The vertical lines are mostly going to be hidden. Various ways of solving that.

Here is your code and my code for an extra graph G2.

```
clear all
input  female scale
 1 3
 1 4
 0 2
 1 4
 0 3
 1 4
 0 2
 1 9
 0 5
 0 6
 1 7
end

su scale if female==1
local female_mean: di %3.2f r(mean)

su scale if female==0
local male_mean: di %3.2f r(mean)

twoway (histogram scale if female == 1, percent discrete xaxis(1 2) xla(`female_mean' "`female_mean'" `male_mean' "`male_mean'", axis(2) format(%9.3f)) xline(`female_mean' `male_mean')) ///
       (histogram scale if female == 0, percent discrete), legend(order(1 "Female" 2 "Male")) name(G1, replace)

* Create scale Histogram by gender
twoway histogram scale if female == 1, barw(0.98) lcolor(orange) fcolor(none) percent discrete xaxis(1 2) xla(`female_mean' `" "female" "`female_mean'" "' `male_mean' `" "male" "`male_mean'" "', axis(2) format(%9.3f)) xtitle("", axis(2)) ///
|| histogram scale if female == 0, barw(0.98) lcolor(blue) fcolor(none) percent discrete legend(order(1 "Female" 2 "Male")) ytitle(Percent) ///
|| scatteri 52 `female_mean' 0 `female_mean', recast(line) lc(blue) ///
|| scatteri 52 `male_mean' 0 `male_mean', recast(line) lc(orange) name(G2, replace)
```

52 is just ad hoc for your example data.

[image]

All that said, something like `twoway histogram scale, by(female)` is likely to work better.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, Nick. I believe the line connecting the labels is due to the graph scheme I am using. I have added the plot I get using your code to my question above. However, as I wish to keep this scheme, I am wondering if there is a way to remove the line.

Comment: That is less puzzling. But -- to be blunt -- you don't tell us as far as I can see what graph scheme you're using and I feel zero responsibility for advising how to work around its bizarre choices! Otherwise put, the line connecting the labels is the x-axis at the top. Why not insist that it has no colour?

Comment: Dear Nick, I believe this problem I am having could be resolved by setting no color for the second x line or alternatively setting the opacity to 0. However, although I can do this for the main x line, I couldn't find a way around to change the color for the second x line. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking that I've not addressed. You can make a line invisible by setting its colour or sometimes by setting its width to zero.